# Content-type and json_encode() values

Tags: php, http-headers, json

Can someone explain this behavior?

in this case:

```
header("Content-type: text/html");
echo json_encode("error_101");
```

it works.

in this other case:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode("error_101");
```

it doesn't work (infinite loading).

But if I pass an array to json_encode, it works in both ways, so this problem exists **only with the json values**.

It seems a bug!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer most data type in a json text **must** be an array or object.

> JSON Grammar
>
> A JSON text is a sequence of tokens.  The set of tokens includes
>   six    structural characters, strings, numbers, and three literal
>   names.
>
> A JSON text is a serialized object or array.
>
> ```
>   JSON-text = object / array
> ```

— http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt

If you pass PHP's `json_encode` function a string, then it will output it as a JavaScript encoded string (instead of throwing an error). I consider this to be a bug.

Presumably, whatever is making the HTTP request to this script is having trouble with the invalid JSON response, but has better error recovery for the invalid HTML.